# The circle of three

Tags: riddle

> I'm the first, but also second
>
> I'm rather odd, but also not
>
> I am the circle of three

What am I?

Comment: For those who liked this puzzle: [The circle of two](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25117/the-circle-of-two).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> 2

I'm the first, but also second

> The first prime, but also the second (depending on convention: 1 used to be regarded as prime).

I'm rather odd, but also not

> 2 is the oddest prime (it is even).

The circle of three

> ???

Comment: You are correct! For solving the third clue, here is a hint: Think of pi instead of the circle. Also, in the first sentence is another clue. First is a synonym of prime, as in e.g. prime minister. And it is the second natural number.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_2$ is only {0,1}. {0, 1, 2} is $\Bbb Z_3$

Comment: The third clue translates to $\pi(3)$, where $\pi(n)$ is the [prime-counting function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html).

Comment: @IvanBarreto That is where I wanted my clue to point to.

Answer (score 11):

You are the

> Second hand in a clock

**Explanation Follows**

I'm the first, but also second

> Second hand is the fastest and to reach the 12 hour mark first. But its calles Second.

I'm rather odd, but also not

> Some time the second hand points to an odd number but in the next instant it will be an even number

I am the circle of three

> The rotation of second hand manages second, minutes (one complete rotation of second hand) and hours (60 complete rotations of second hand). The numbers/points in circular form in a clock represents seconds, minutes and hours.

Comment: Very close, and good explanation, but not where I was looking for.

Comment: The last clue fits more to the number marks in the clock. May be that's what your intended answer is. :)

Comment: No that is also not the correct answer. In fact, your original answer is closer.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> a clock

I'm the first, but also second

> the first to show the time and the seconds in the time

I'm rather odd, but also not

> the hour, minute and second can be odd numbers and also can be not odd *i.e.* even

The circle of three

> a clock is a circle with three hands

Comment: No, you removed the wrong part from the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> the hands of a clock

I'm the first, but also second

> The second hand also the minute hand both go all the way around?

I'm rather odd, but also not

> The hour, minute and second can be odd numbers and also even

The circle of three

> Minute, hour and second hands

Comment: Nope, it is not a part of a clock.