# The circle of two

Tags: riddle

Inspired by the succes of [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/the-circle-of-three), here is another riddle:

> Smaller than the Great Graham!
>
> Smaller than the monster, but also much greater than the monster,
>
> am I equal to two-in-a-circle.

What am I?

**Note:** If you include the full answer, you will hit the character limit for answers (30000 characters). Please use an abbreviation. Yes, this is a clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> [Mega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Moser_notation#Mega)

`Smaller than the Great Graham!`

> Smaller than [Graham's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number)

`Smaller than the monster, but also much greater than the monster,`

> **EDIT**: 'mega' is the prefix for 1000<sup>2</sup>, 'tera', from the Greek for "monster" (thanks, @wythagoras!), is the prefix for 1000<sup>4</sup>. So *a* Mega is much greater than *tera-* anything, lowercase-m mega is smaller than its tera counterpart.

`am I equal to two-in-a-circle.`

> See link for first spoilertag

Comment: You are right, but not about the second clue. Hint: Think of Mega as a smaller number, and translate monster into Greek.

Comment: @wythagoras I edited my answer, thank you for the push

Comment: @question_asker, Yes, that is correct.